# How to use a proxy that requires authorization without exposing credentials (username and password)

Tags: networking, password, proxy, authentication

There are knows ways to setup internet and system updates access through a proxy by setting the environment variables (`http_proxy=`) and/or updates' config options (like `Acquire::Http::Proxy`).

There are solutions for cases of proxies that require authentication by using the `username:password` before the proxy URL. However, these solutions require the username and the password to be specified in plaintext. These solutions also doesn't (or only partially) covers the multi-user cases.

Is there a way to make a proxy specifications, that doesn't expose pre-defined login-password but ask for them or get them from per-user basis?